# Unity Script C#, Array to list, How to Optimize object detection in a better way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on RTS game and need a better way for units to deter each other.

When each unit is doing this, at around 30 units this starts to become very expensive way to run things.

What would be a better way to optimize this:

```
private void Update()
{
 if(target == null) 
        {
            ArrayDetect();
            AttackUnit();
            return;  
        }

[SerializeField] private Collider[] colliderArray;
    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> enemyColliders;


   
    private void ArrayDetect()
    {
       colliderArray = Physics.OverlapSphere(ownAimAtPoint.position, fireRange, layerMask);
       
       
       foreach (Collider collider in colliderArray)
        {
                Debug.Log("we hit a", collider);                if(!collider.TryGetComponent<Targetable>(out Targetable potentialTarget)) 
                {
                    return;                   
                }    
                if (potentialTarget.hasAuthority)
                    {     
                    return;  
                    }
                
                else
                {
                enemyColliders = enemyColliders.Distinct().ToList();
                enemyColliders.Add(collider.gameObject);
                Debug.Log("Found an enemy", potentialTarget);
                }                
        }
    }
```

Physics.OverlapSphere to find colliders in range with layermask tag, then sort through them and add them to a enemy List
then:

```
private void AttackUnit()
    {
        //if (enemyColliders.Count == 0) { return; }

        foreach (GameObject enemy in enemyColliders)
        {
         Debug.Log("We got confirmed enemy", enemy);
gameObject.GetComponent<Targeter>().CmdSetTarget(enemy);
                //attack the enemy

        }
        
    }
```

go through enemy List and assign each enemy as a target to attack.

Comment: [This Unity Thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/performance-issues-with-rts-game-constantly-searching-for-enemy-units.792924/) looks like a golden mine for you. At the very bottom OP explains what helped him going from 32 FPS to 112 FPS. Also someone mentioned **UNITY DOTS**. Unity DOTS is really efficient than standard functions but try it if you have a lot of spare time for learning new things.

Comment: Just a starting point can be removing that `TryGetComponent` Check by **not including objects that are not tagetable.**

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Comment: If you want easy optimization, start with assigning `gameObject.GetComponent<Targeter>()` to a field during Start(). Second, there is no reason why you for looped all colliders, allocating enemies to a list, and then for looping the enemies, whereas could be one single for loop.